# Using pcolor to plot an electric field in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

My name is Alex and I am new on programming on Matlab. I am writing a code to plot the contour of an electric field on a x-y axis. I am using pcolor(x,y,real(E)) in order to do that. Then, I use shading interp to show the different colors of my electric field on a plane x-y. 
First of all, I have a vector with some values R that represent radii of circles. Then, I transform the vector r (cylindrical coordinates) into x and y vectors (Cartesian coordinates) with the code

This is the code I used to create the image

```
r=(125/2)*1e-6;
a0=(105/2)*1e-6;
a=(81/2)*1e-9;
z=2*1e-3; 
theta=(pi*19)/180;
lambda=632*1e-9; 

n1=1.445;
n2=1.433;
delta = sqrt(n1^2 - n2^2);
Kco=n1*2*pi/lambda;
V=(2*pi*delta*a0)/lambda;

z=linspace(0,z,500);
g=zeros(1,length(z));

r=linspace(r,a,length(z));


B = zeros(1,length(r));

psi = zeros(length(r),length(r));
E = zeros(1,length(r));
M=length(z)

g = (a0)./(a+z*theta);

R=(g')*r;

beta = linspace(0,2*pi,length(z));
for i=1:length(z)
    w = R(i);
    w = repmat(w,[length(z) 1]);
    [X Y] = pol2cart(beta,w');
    x(i,:) = X;
    y(i,:)=Y;

    clear w;
    clear X Y;


end

for i=1:length(r)

    if r(i)<=a0
        n1=1.445;
        n2=1;
   delta = sqrt(n1^2 - n2^2);
    end
     R02(i)=(a0^2)./(((delta*2*pi*(a+z(i)*theta)/lambda)-1));

     psi(i,:)=exp(-(x(i,:).^2+y(i,:).^2)./(2*R02(i))) ;
end
clear R02




B=sqrt(Kco^2 -((2*V).*g)./(a0^2)+(g.^2)./(a0^2));
for i=1:length(r)
E(i,:) = sqrt(x(i,:).^2+y(i,:).^2).*psi(i,:).*(exp(-1i*(B(i)).*z(i)));
end


pcolor(x,y,real(E));

shading interp
```

z in this part is the z-axis and this vector has some values too.
So the electric field is a function of x,y and z after the transformation for cartesian coordinates. Now, I am ready to plot the graph and I get
[image]

But it should have more colors than the image has shown there. All I have done is simulation. There is no data from experiments. But it does not shows what the experiment shows. Any help is very appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please give us a complete example to reproduce your problem, including the input data and the code you are using to plot.

Comment: Please provide the part of code you used to produce the plot on the picture

Comment: hat is because the limits you are putting on your colormap limit. You can probably fix this with a `clims` call, but hard to tell without the data/plotting code

Comment: Agree with @AnderBiguri , you probably have data that is mostly beyond your colormap limit e.g. 255, so everything above is shown red.

Comment: can you provide all the code including for the plotting and also initialization of `z` and `R`?

Comment: I just edited my post. I wrote the code above but it is not working as I said.